# Java LinkedList has empty constructor in its source code

Tags: java

Is what I write below about LinkedList.java in jdk-8u111 correct?

> ```
> /**
>  * Constructs an empty list.
>  */
> public LinkedList() {
> }
> ```
>
> We can see there exists no code in the constructor and the purpose of
>   such a strange constructor is for later subclasses. As we know that
>   the compiler would automatically provide a no-argument `super()` to
>   a subclass constructor if the constructor has no explicit `super()`
>   call. The compiler would report an error if the parent class had no such
>   no-argument constructor.
>
> ```
> Error:(x, y) java: no suitable constructor found for parent class(no arguments)
> ```
>
> We can conclude that the empty constructor of `LinkedList` is for subclass use.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's nothing to do with subclasses.

If you don't define any constructors then Java will automatically add a default constructor. However, if you do define other constructors then the default constructor must be written out. Because this constructor exists:

```
LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c);
```

The default constructor must be explicitly defined:

```
LinkedList();
```

---

> It works and has no error if I do not write out an explicit empty default constructor. The compiler executes successfully. So it is okay not to write it out? What is the need to write it out if we already have another constructor?

- With no constructors, a default one is added and we can successfully call `new Thing()`:

  ```
  class Thing {
  }

  Thing t = new Thing();
  ```
- With a non-default constructor added, Java no longer adds a default constructor on its own. Now `new Thing()` is an error.

  ```
  class Thing {
      public Thing(int foo) { }
  }

  Thing t = new Thing();
  ```

  Result:

  ```
  Test.java:7: error: constructor Thing in class Thing cannot be applied to given types;
          Thing t = new Thing();
                    ^
    required: int
    found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  1 error
  ```
- We must write out the default constructor for the code to compile:

  ```
  class Thing {
      public Thing() { }
      public Thing(int foo) { }
  }

  Thing t = new Thing();
  ```

Comment: hello John: thanks so much that I made it clear now. To write out default constructor is to help initialization by new a object with non-arguments. But the default constructor can not be used and can be deleted if we always use other constructor instead default one. Further having no default constructor would cause its subclass have to explicitly call super() with argument because compiler supplied super() for the subclass, which is fixed with non-argument, would report error.